# Why doesn't Python enter the def of one class while it does enter the def of another?

Tags: python

So, below are two classes. When I run unittest on them (`python -m unittest -v unit_test`, where this code is saved as "unit_test.py") then the tests in the second class are executed, but not those in the first. Any clue what could be going wrong?

Everything important seems to be identical, but Python is just skipping from the `def setUp(self):` line of the first class down to the second class. (Because it skips there, I don't think it's relevant to post the `hac.process_lines()` code that shows up in that class.) Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
class TestClient(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Tests the central clause of the program                                                                        
    """
    def setUp(self):                                                                                               
        self.store = {}                                                                                            
        self.example_1 = ['set foo bar', 'get foo', 'set baz bat', 'list',                                         
        'delete foo', 'get baz']                                                                                   
        self.example_2 = ['auth test testpw', 'set foo bar', 'get foo', 'set \                                     
        baz bat', 'list', 'delete foo', 'get baz']                                                                 

    def correct_dictionary_v1(self):                                                                               
        self.store = hac.process_lines(self.example_1)                                                             
        self.assertEqual(self.store, {'baz': 'bat'})                                                               

    def correct_dictionary_v2(self):                                                                               
        self.store = hac.process_lines(self.example_2)                                                             
        self.assertEqual(self.store, {'baz': 'bat'})


class TestGetValue(unittest.TestCase):                                                                             
    """                                                                                                            
    Tests the 'get' command function                                                                               
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.store = {}                                                                                            
        self.key = 'key'
        self.value = 'value'                                                                                       

    def test_good_input(self):
        self.store = {'key': 'value'}                                                                              
        self.assertEqual('value', hac.get_value(self.store, self.key))                                             

    def test_missing_key(self):
        self.store = {}                                                                                            
        self.assertEqual(1, hac.get_value(self.store, self.key))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tests must begin with a name that starts with `'test'`. So to run the tests in the first class, change `correct_dictionary_v1` to `test_correct_dictionary_v1`, and `correct_dictionary_v2` to `test_correct_dictionary_v2`.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code):

> TestLoader uses the 'test' method name prefix to identify test methods automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A test case's `setUp` method is run before each test method. Your `TestClient` has no test methods. If you want `correct_dictionary_v1` and `v2` to be test methods, make them start with the word "test".